# Solr and spelling exclude short words in result

Tags: solr, lucene

I have a lot of crappy words in my index just using my data with the example that comes with. This makes the spelling suggestions pretty bad.

For example  it suggests a lot of random 1-3 char long words. Example:

query carr: ca ar c a r car rr carrot.

I would like the spelling query to ignore all those useless words. They are not really known stop words but rather random abbreviations. I have also not figured out how to skip one letter words during indexing yet...

Also if you search for arrot you never find carrot. How can that be achieved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the field type definition for field you use for suggestions, you can use LengthFilterFactory - set the min to 3, and you won't see the short words indexed at all.

See: https://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.LengthFilterFactory

For the second part of the question, you could use in your field definition

```
<filter class="EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="2" maxGramSize="15" side="back" />
```

this will generate nGrams from the end of the word (ot, rot, rrot, arrot). It depends on your specifics of how you generate and process your queries though.

Comment: Exception writing document id 1 to the index; possible analysis error. For the EdgeNGram, any clue why?

Comment: Paste the exception? Did you try from an empty index, just to be sure?

Comment: Hello, nGram back was removed. Now you are supposed to use     <filter class="solr.ReverseStringFilterFactory" /> no success with it yet but I keep learning.

Seems when I add that factory it wrecks everything so perhaps it needs it's own field? wdyt?

Comment: It won't hurt to try; the error message isn't informative at all?

Comment: It was. I needed ReverseStringFilterFactory. Now I am just trying to use it effeciently